# ASP.NET Core event based background tasks with hosted services

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0

I am having some trouble with while loops and events using background tasks in ASP.NET Core hosted services. I am trying to get my Progress_Changed event to fire from within the `while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)` part so I can capture data continuously while the app is running. I have been following these guides:

[Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice)

[Implement background tasks in microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

How can I capture events while keeping the BackgroundService in a continuous loop so I am always able to get data? I am hoping to use this with SignalR so I can feed out data to a hub.

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ICustomService _service;
    private IProgress<JSONMessage> _progress;

    public MyBackgroundService(ICustomService service)
    {
        _service = service;
        _progress = new Progress<JSONMessage>();
        _progress.ProgressChagned += Progress_Changed;
    {

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _service.StartService(_progress);

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private void Progress_Changed(object s, JSONMessage e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is currently happening when you run this code?  In other words, what's wrong with it?  Exceptions, behavior, etc...

Comment: The event fires early on, or at least when I am stepping through the code, but on a straight run it never outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Having long running tasks within IIS can be tricky for a variety of reasons. It's probably easier to delegate this kind of stuff to a library that *just works* like Hangfire. https://www.hangfire.io/.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but this seems like a possible deadlock to me.  By default `await` captures the current `SynchronizationContext` and then posts back to it upon completion.  This gets pretty dicey in IIS/ASP.NET for many reasons I won't get into.  Try this code instead:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _service.StartService(_progress).ConfigureAwait(false);

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

The only change made here is disabling the postback to the captured context I spoke about.  Please be aware this means you're potentially on a different thread after the call to `await`.  Because of this you could consider this a hack, but I see nothing in the method that requires a postback.

If that doesn't fix it I would attach a debugger to the *release* build.  Or use a profiler to see what exactly is happening.